# Issue with too many arguments to function

Tags: c++, computer-science

I'm currently working on a homework assignment for my computer science I course and I'm a newbie on C++. however, when I compile the program it said that it has **too many arguments to function 'void results()'**

can someone please explain to how I can fix this issue. Your time will be well appreciated.

**Below is the description for the assignment**

I need to create a program that implements functions to convert a temperature from either scale to its corresponding value in the other.
Using F to represent a Fahrenheit temperature and C to represent a Celsius temperature, the following formulas are used to convert between the two temperature scales

F = 1.8C +32
C = F-32/1.8

the program must prompt the user for the scale and degree measurement of the initial temperature and display both the Fahrenheit and Celsius equivalents of the temperature provided, rounded to two decimal places.  If inappropriate input is provided for either the scale or temperature, the program must display an appropriate error message and terminate execution without displaying any results.  Appropriate input for the temperature scale will depend on how the information is obtained; appropriate temperatures are any values greater than or equal to absolute zero, which is -459.67 F or -273.15 C.

The main function of the program may only contain variable declarations and function calls.  To process data, as a minimum, your program must make proper use of a proper function for each of the following tasks, although you may include as many additional functions as you desire:

1.Display a brief overview and/or set of instructions explaining the program to the user

2.Have the user enter the temperature scale used

3.Have the user enter the initial temperature reading

4.Convert a Fahrenheit temperature to Celsius

5.Convert a Celsius temperature to Fahrenheit

6.Display the results

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

// Prototype
void overView();
void results();
char tempScale();
float tempReading();
float convertFtoC(float);
float convertCtoF(float);

int main(){


    overView ();
    cout << setprecision (2) << fixed;

    float degree = tempReading();
    char scale = tempScale();
    float fahrenheit, celsius;

    if(scale == 'F'){
          celsius = convertFtoC(degree);
          fahrenheit = degree;

    }
    else if (scale == 'C'){
          fahrenheit = convertCtoF(degree);
          celsius = degree;
    }
    else{
        cout << "***Error: Invalid temperature Scale Please try again!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    results(fahrenheit, celsius);

   return 0;

}

// this function was build to give an overview to the user explaining the program
void overView(){
    cout << "This program will convert a temperature reading provided in" << endl;
    cout << "either Fahrenheit or Celsius to the other measurement scale." << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

// this function was build to ask the user to chose the temperature scale
char tempScale(){
    char scale;
    cout << "Please chose the temperature scale that you wish to use (F = Fahrenheit; C = Celsius): ";
    cin >> scale;
    return scale;
}

// this function was build to ask the user to enter the temperature reading in degree
float tempReading(){
    float degree;
    cout << "Please enter your temperature reading (in degrees): ";
    cin >> degree;
    return degree;
}

// This function was build to converts a Fahrenheit temperature to celsius
float convertFtoC(float fahrenheit){
    float celsius;
    celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) / 1.8;
    return celsius;
}

// This function was build to converts a Celsius temperature to Fahrenheit
float convertCtoF(float celsius){

    float fahrenheit;
    fahrenheit = 1.8 * (celsius + 32);
    return fahrenheit;

}

// This function will display the results to the user
void results(float fahrenheit, float celsius){

cout <<"Your temperature reading converts as follows:" << endl;
cout << "Fahrenheit: " << fahrenheit << endl;
cout << "Celsius: " << celsius << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your forward function declaration change `void results();` to `void results(float, float);`. The error is basically saying "you defined a function with no parameters however your are calling it with two parameters".

Answer (score 1):

Your prototype doesn't have the parameters, so C++ thinks you're doing something wrong (it expects no inputs).

Changing:

```
// Prototype
void overView();
void results();
```

to

```
// Prototype
void overView();
void results(float fahrenheit, float celsius);
```

Should fix it! C++ tends to take your prototype more seriously than your implementation. This also happens in C.

Comment: _"C++ tends to take your prototype more seriously than your implementation"_ What do you mean _takes more seriously_? The function signatures in declaration and definition must match exactly, that's all.

Comment: That's what I mean. If given the choice to make your prototype be wrong or your function call, it will always choose your function call. This is what I mean by "more seriously", but I can see how that would be misleading.